# Create socks host with C# for http proxy forwarding

Tags: c#, proxy, websocket, socks

i want to create a proxy server or (Socks host ??) to communicate with browsers (such as firefox) to forward http proxy.

i have a software that do this: bitvise tunnelier.

so, i need to write an application similiar to tunnelier proxy forwarder.

in other words, i want to enable firefox Socks Host and get browser request with c# application

Please help me lead the way

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Create a proxy means that your application need to act as an HTTP Server when talking to the clients (the browsers) and act as a browser when comunicating with the web sites.
The proxy opens a port for the server socket (for example port 90) and accepts the browser request on this port, than connect the web site (generally on port 80) and forward the request to the site server. The proxy waits for the server response, read it and after send the response to the client.
The proxy changes the messages header if needed ( for example change the port in the url).
In general proxy are multi thread applications, so they can manage more request in the same time.

Comment: thanks for reply, i wrote a socket server application that listens on 127.0.0.1:7777 and configure browser socks host to 127.0.0.1:7777. but browser just sent a "|" character to socks server, why ?

Comment: @RaminMousavi snoop the cominication to see what really send the browser, you could post part of the code that could help to find an answer